# increase value until limit then decrease loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I try to increase the value of a variable `valuem` from 0 to 10 and if the value of `valuem` is 10 it should decrease until the value is 0, then again increase until 10 and so on.

for example: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 ...

what is the simplest and efficientest way to do that?

```
var valuem = 0;
$('#number').text(valuem);

function count() {
    valuem++;
    $('#number').text(valuem);

    if (valuem == 10) {
        valuem--;
        $('#number').text(valuem);
    }

}

setInterval(count, 1000);
```

Comment: [Check this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/dwu2ghuj/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This way:

```js
var valuem = 0, dir = 1;
$('#number').text(valuem);

function count() {
  valuem += dir;
  $('#number').text(valuem);
  if (valuem < 1) dir = 1;
  if (valuem > 9) dir = -1;
}

setInterval(count, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="number"></div>
```

You have to store the counting direction as the part of the state besides the current number to know in which direction to count when `valuem` is between 1 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one might simplify it more by just using the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_%28%29) with an offset. This way the entire calculation is done in a single line without any if statements.

```js
var n = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  number.innerHTML = 10 - Math.abs(n++ % 20 - 10);
}, 500);
```

```html
<h1 id="number"></h1>
```